# cvtsd2si instruction not truncating correctly?

Tags: x86, floating-point, x86-64, sse

I want to generate a random number from 1 to 10 using x86_64 assembly (Clang on macOS). Here is what I am doing to try to achieve that:

1. Random 32-bit number from `rdrand`
2. Divide it by the 32-bit maximum, which should get me a float from 0 to 1
3. Multiply it by 10
4. Truncate it to an integer and store that in `rdi`

This is not working. An LLDB trace revealed that `rdi` contained 9223372036854775808, which was very unexpected. What am I doing wrong here?

```
    .global _main
    .text
_main:
    rdrand rsi
    mov [storage + rip], rsi
    movsd xmm0, qword ptr [storage + rip]
    divsd xmm0, qword ptr [MAX_32 + rip]  # ratio
    mov qword ptr [storage + rip], 10  # mul by 10
    mulsd xmm0, qword ptr [storage + rip]

    cvtsd2si rdi, xmm0  # why is rdi not reasonable?

    /*
    What I want to happen:

    1. I get a random number from 1 to MAX_32
    2. I divide that by MAX_32
    3. I multiply it by 10
    That means that rdi should contain a number from 1 to 10. But LLDB shows this:

    (lldb) register read rdi
        rdi = 0x8000000000000000

    0x8000000000000000 = 9223372036854775808, which is too big

    What is going wrong here?
    */

    mov rax, 0x2000001
    syscall

    .data
storage:
    .quad 0
MAX_32:
    .quad 2147483647
```

Comment: `cvtsd2si` converts with round-to-nearest (or whatever the default rounding mode is). 
 `cvttsd2si` truncates.  Obviously that's not your only problem (because it would just be an off-by-1), but what I was expecting from just the title.

Comment: `movsd xmm0, qword ptr [storage + rip]` - why are you reloading a random 64-bit integer as a double-precision bit-pattern, instead of converting the integer to a `double`?   About half the IEEE754 binary64 (aka `double`) bit-patterns represent a number less than 1.0.  Also, the integer `.quad 2147483647` represents (as a `double`) a very tiny subnormal value with zeroes everywhere but near the bottom of the mantissa.  Also, `rdrand rsi` produces an 64-bit integer which you should probably treat as unsigned.

Comment: Anyway, `9223372036854775808` is the integer-indefinite value (`0x8000000...`) which you get when the actual integer value doesn't fit in the destination, as the manual explains https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cvtsd2si.  From there, you'd debug by printing the `$xmm0.v2_double` or whatever LLDB calls it to see the double value you converted from, and work backwards from there to find your mistakes.

Comment: Just wondering - is this meant as an exercise in floating point, or are you genuinely just trying to get random numbers between 1 and 10?  There are purely integer algorithms that are simpler and less biased: discard any value >= the largest multiple of 10 below 2^32, then take remainder mod 10.

Comment: @NateEldredge I am actually trying to get a random number between 1 and ten. Later on I want to expand this to any start and stop range.